# "Compiling" go project as C shared object library on AIX 7.2 results in Executable that doesn't run

Tags: c, go, gcc, aix, powerpc

**EDIT:** For any poor soul that finds this, in search of a solution for the shared library from go conundrum: I was unable to find a solution that uses go and I would suggest, that until google go provides native c-shared support for AIX you should find an alternative for your project.

I did not go forward with gccgo because that felt like an entirely different can of worms that I was unwilling to delve further into. FWIW I myself am going forward switching to pure C implementation, because there I at least have a (somewhat) firm(er) understanding of it all.

Should anyone find a solution I'd love to hear from you and see how you got around this limitation.

---

Environment:
AIX 7.2
go1.16.12 aix/ppc64
gcc-8

I want to create a C shared object library (in usual unix vernacular a .so file) out of a golang project on AIX 7.2 so that it can be used by a C application.
I can compile it down to a final a.out binary in my example, but it can then not be executed because the shared object is apparently compiled the wrong way.

So far I have achieved the following:

Suppose my example go "library" sharedLibTest.go:

```
package main

import (
m   "fmt"
)

import "C"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", "Golang: main was called")
    MyPackage_Init()
    MyPackage_Create()
}

//export MyPackage_Init
func MyPackage_Init() {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", "Golang: MyPackage_Init was called")
}

//export MyPackage_Create
func MyPackage_Create() {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", "Golang: MyPackage_Create was called")
}
```

And some C application that calls these functions in main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sharedLibTest.h"

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", "C: main() called");
    MyPackage_Init();
    MyPackage_Create();
}
```

m
Now, because AIX feels the need to do things differently the current golang toolchain does not support directly creating a c-shared object with `-buildmode=c-shared`. Instead I am trying to do the roundabout way by first creating a static lib with `-buildmode=c-archive`, compiling that into a shared object using gcc-8 and use that in my "target C application".

I can compile sharedLibTest.go this with

```
go build -v -buildmode=c-archive -mod vendor -o /home/myuser/workspace/go_proj/sharedLibTest/sharedLibTest.a /home/myuser/workspace/go_proj/sharedLibTest/sharedLibTest.go
```

Because the symbols `MyPackage_Init` and `MyPackage_Create` are not exported by default in AIX, I need to manually create an extra symbol file with

```
$ cat > file.exp << EOF
> MyPackage_Init
> MyPackage_Create
> EOF
```

[Source](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/48670)
(If there are any ideas how i can omit this file.exp step I'd really appreciate it)

Now with that I can compile a shared object out of that by running

```
gcc -g -O2 -mcpu=power7 -maix64 -shared -lpthread -Wl,-bE:file.exp -o libsharedLibTest.so -Wl,-bnoobjreorder ./sharedLibTest.a
```

Now because AIX does not look for .so files but only .a files even if they are shared libraries, I rename the resulting libsharedLibTest.so into libsharedLibTest.a with

```
mv libsharedLibTest.so libsharedLibTest.a
```

Lastly I want to compile my C applications with

```
gcc -L/home/myuser/workspace/go_proj/sharedLibTest -g -O2 -mcpu=power7 -maix64 -Wl,-bnoobjreorder -lsharedLibTest -lpthreads main.c
```

This succeeds and I get my a.out file as a result.
However, when I try to run this with the following, I only get the error below

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myuser/workspace/go_proj/sharedLibTest ./a.out

$ ./a.out 
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program ./a.out because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module /home/myuser/workspace/go_proj/sharedLibTest/libsharedLibTest.a(libsharedLibTest.so) could not be loaded.
        0509-187 The local-exec model was used for thread-local
                   storage, but the module is not the main program.
        0509-193 Examine the .loader section header with the
                 'dump -Hv' command.
```

Some hours of googling so far have revealed that I might be missing the compile option -fPIC to create "emit position-independent code" however adding that flag to any of the above steps in various combinations has all resulted in the same error.

Clearly I need to add some compile option to tell the shared object not to be thread-local, however I am unclear how. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you let go of _go_ language? AIX in itself is exotic enough, there is no need to use an exotic programming language as well. You can use C language for your shared objects. Nonetheless you can try `export CGO_CFLAGS="-fPIC -DPIC"` before compiling your go-source.

Comment: No, go is meant to stay for this process and the application planned is imo too complex to write it in plain C. 
I will try the exported ENV variable to see if that passes the flags properly.
Side note: Kubernetes and Docker are written in go, I think the time is long past to call go "exotic".

Comment: Seen any success yet?

Comment: As far as my own efforts go, I buried this specific project idea. We considered implementing our application in plain C to compile it as a shared lib but the effort necessary was deemed too high.  Now we are moving forward with a daemon approach that offers the lib functionality as a service, all written in golang.

Answer (score 0):

Few points... **mv** will not make an archieve, **ar** will. You need to use **ar** command to create **.a** file.
Second, use LIBPATH environment variable in place of LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Use of -fPIC option is irrelevant on AIX.

Comment: About renaming *.so to *.a: It is an AIX speciality: the linker (used without the `-brtl` flag) ignores *.so files, but handles *.a files, even if they are shared-objects, not ar-archives.